# Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to import Excel data into SQL Server 2012.

Excel columns:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
```

SQL Server table structure:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
```

I want the Excel data stored into the SQL Server table that has same column name as in the Excel sheet, with auto increment in SQL Server.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used SQL Integration Service  SSIS?
If you would like to code I would suggest using sql bulk insert.

The alternative is to do a concatenation in Excel if you are comfortable with that

```
=concatenate("INSERT INTO myTable (Col, Col2, Col3) VALUES ('",A1,"','",A2,"','",A3,"');")
```

Then populate the whole sheet and submit to db